# How to hide CMD/BAT WITHOUT using Vbscript

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hide

How to hide CMD/BAT WITHOUT using Vbscript, I dont like using VBSCRIPT because it slows down application before it autorun. So if you have a code to put into batch or CMD to hide the CMD/Bat file WITHOUT using VBScrpit. please let me know. thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Do you want to hide the command prompt window (the black box)? How are you calling it?

Comment: Please, explain what exactly you want to do. If you want to _minimize or hide the MS-DOS window_, then I have an .exe program that do that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing that once and never really succeeded.  Here is my sample code, which is the closest that I got to the solution:

```
@echo off
if not defined PIL (
    set PIL=1
    start /min "" %~0
    exit /b
)
TITLE Hello World
echo Hello world!
pause>nul
```